# How to append text from one span to another?

Tags: jquery

How do I catch the text "Copy me" and append it inside the id "#copy"?

```
<span id="text">Copy me</span>
<span id="copy"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this

```js
$("#copy").append($("#text").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="text">Copy me</span>
<span id="copy"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#copy').html($('#text').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="text">Copy me</span>
<span id="copy"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#copy').text($('#text').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="text">Copy me</span>
<span id="copy"></span>
```